# how to enable soft tabs textmate2

Tags: textmate2

i've seen some other answers to this but my textmate is behaving funny.  i can't enable the soft tabs, which is getting annoying now that I'm working with haml.  any ideas?

attached screenshot, the softtabs option is greyed out.  what am I missing?

thanks,
JD

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want Soft Tabs enabled everywhere add the following to the `.tm_properties` file in your home dir. If you don't have it just create one.

If you want to enable it for a specific project only simply create a `.tm_properties` file in the project dir.

```
softTabs = true
tabSize  = 4
```

If you want to enable Soft Tab only for certain file types you can add a section to the file like this:

```
[ *.coffee ]
softTabs = true
tabSize = 2
```

I would recommend you to check out how these files work. Here is [an example by hmans](https://github.com/hmans/homedir/blob/master/.tm_properties).

Also check out [Textmate 2 Tips](http://tm2tips.tumblr.com/) for more info.

**Update**

As Michael Sheets writes in his answer, it is now possible to save the change through the GUI.

Comment: it is interesting as I've seen this technique and had tried it to no avail.  i should be asking myself what governs where my system is looking for my configuration files.  i'm a relatively new dev, so when i set my machine up for serious work this prior may, i have a feeling i changed something that is messing with this. i've had a lot of trouble getting terminal to load color profiles as well.  thx.

Answer (score 0):

As of r9290 you can now change the tab settings from the menu at the bottom of the edit window and they will be saved for the current file type and parent file type if applicable.

These are saved into `Global.tmProperties` which you can read more about in the release notes for `r9290` (Help → Release Notes).